# vertx-web-client testing always times out, even though the assertion succeeds

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertx-verticle

##### Problem:

I am using the vertx-web-graphql dependency to run a graphql-server and now I want to test that said server.

But the vertx-web-client testing always times out, even after the assertion that is just before the testContext.completeNow() does not fail.

##### Versions:

- Kotlin (1.7.20)
- vertx(core, graphql, postgres, web-client, vertx-junit5) (4.3.4)

##### Problem-Code:

```
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension::class)
class GraphQlVerticleTest {

    @BeforeEach
    fun `deploy GraphQL Verticle`(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
      vertx.deployVerticle(GraphQlVerticle(setupPostgreSqlClient(vertx), setupJWTAuthenticationProvider(vertx)),
                           testContext.succeedingThenComplete())
    }

    @Test
    fun `Wrong Login Credentials cause Login Failed message`(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
        val webClient: WebClient = WebClient.create(vertx)
      
        testContext.assertComplete(webClient.post(graphQLPort, graphQLHostName, graphQLURI)
                                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .sendJsonObject(createLoginAttemptQueryAsJsonObject(wrongEmail, wrongPassword)))
          .onComplete { asyncResult ->
              assertThat(asyncResult.result().bodyAsString()).isEqualTo(loginFailedResponse)
              println("hello I executed")
              testContext.completeNow()
          }
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun `check that the Verticle is still there`(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
        assertThat(vertx.deploymentIDs()).isNotEmpty.hasSize(1)
    }
}
```

The Verticle and some of the functions don't really matter, as the Assert Statement **does not fail**, but for some reason the testContext never gets completed and then the Test times out.

I used the testContext.assertComplete(...).onComplete(...) in all my other Vertx-Tests, but with the Web-Client it just does not work.
As far as I can tell, in this scenario the test-context has to be completed in different way, but I just can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated .
And please tell me if there is anything to make the question clearer, as I have never asked anything on StackOverflow before.

##### What I tried:

I tried placing the the assertion and testContext completion statement into a testContext.verify {} block, but that didn't work either. I read through the vertx-junit5 & vertx-web-client documentation, but there wasn't anything there concerning web-client testing. And my search didn't had any fruitful results either.

##### What I expected:

That the test would complete after the assertion statement succeeded, like it did in all my other vertx-tests.

Comment: The the println print? Can you try onSuccess/onFailure instead of onComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: you must complete the testContext in the method annotated with @AfterEach:

```
@AfterEach
fun `check that Verticle is still there`(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {
    assertThat(vertx.deploymentIDs()).isNotEmpty.hasSize(1)
    testContext.completeNow()
}
```

Or simply not inject it:

```
@AfterEach
fun `check that Verticle is still there`(vertx: Vertx) {
    assertThat(vertx.deploymentIDs()).isNotEmpty.hasSize(1)
}
```

In both cases, the test passes.

*Originally posted by @tsegismont in https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-junit5/issues/122#issuecomment-1315619893*